# why XHR returns 404 for youtube links that redirects?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, youtube, xmlhttprequest

(I use kango framework http://kangoextensions.com/kango.html)

This url https://www.youtube.com/CalvinHarrisVEVO redirects to https://www.youtube.com/**user**/CalvinHarrisVEVO

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", 'https://www.youtube.com/CalvinHarrisVEVO', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

The returned status code is 404, but in PHP is 301, how can I get the right status code via XHR, or what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get status 0 (which is what I'd expect for a cross origin request).

Comment: btw, sorry, I use kango framework

Comment: but if you use inspect element you`ll see 404 Not Found

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.youtube.com/CalvinHarrisVEVO"